# Solution for task using number theory and group theory.

Tags: number-theory

$$p \mid b^n +1 \text{ and } p \text{ is prime }  \Rightarrow$$

(1) $ p\mid b^d +1$  where $d$ is  some proper  divisor of $n$ such that $\frac{n}{d}$ is odd

or

(2) $p=1 \pmod {2n}$

I'm tried to solve it many times, but I didn't manage.
I would like somebody explain me solution or give an advice (helpful advice ;)) how to solve it using group theory ($ Z_p^*$) and without this theory. (maybe Fermat's Assume?- I'm not sure).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be the smallest  positive integer such that $b^k \equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

Fermat's little theorem implies $k\mid p-1$.

By assumption, we have $k\mid 2n$ and $k \not\mid n$.

So we may write $k=2 k_0$ with $k_0\mid n$ and $2k_0\not\mid n$. Since $(b^{k_0}+1)(b^{k_0}-1)\equiv 0$, we get $b^{k_0}+1=0$; for $b^{k_0}-1\not \equiv 0$.

Case 1: if $k_0$ is a proper divisor of $n$.

Case 2: If $k_0=n$.